# Formatting awk output to resemble JSON object

Tags: json, linux, bash, apache, awk

I'm trying to get the output of an awk command to be formatted into a JSON. I don't have much experience with awk or regex to get this to format correctly. The script is taking raw data from Apache by tailing the access logs and parsing out the data I want using awk.

I've spent about an hour googling and trying different formats. The best setup I currently have is the following code.

awk:

```
awk -F " " '{
    print "{\"ipAddr\":\"" $1 "\",\"reqType\":\"" $4 "\",\"reqItem\":\"" $5 
        "\",\"reqStatus\":\"" $7 "\",\"reqUrl\":\"" $8 "\"}"
}' temp1.log >> hmReq.log;
```

The output I'm currently getting is:

```
{"{\"ipAddr\":\"my.ip.Addr\",
\"reqType\":\"GET\",
\"reqItem\":\"/contact\",
\"reqStatus\":\"200\",
\"reqUrl\":\"\"https://www.example.com/\"\"}":""}
```

I'm trying to get it to be like so:

```
{
"ipAddr":"123.456.789.0", 
"reqType":"GET", 
"reqItem":"/contact", 
"reqStatus":"200",
 "reqUrl":"www.com"
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
This is the entire script:

```
inotifywait -m ~/hmLogs/a2access.log -e modify | while read path action file; do
        cd ~/hmLogs
        tail -n1 a2access.log >> temp1.log;
        awk -F " " '{
            print "{\"ipAddr\":\"" $1 "\",\"reqType\":\"" $4 "\",\"reqItem\":\"" 
                $5 "\",\"reqStatus\":\"" $7 "\",\"reqUrl\":\"" 
                $8 "\"}"}' temp1.log >> hmReq.log;
        curl -s -w "\n" -d @hmReq.log -X POST http://localhost:8080/logs >> hmRes.log;
        rm hmReq.log;
        rm temp1.log;
        cd -;
done;
```

Sample of raw data input from apache2/access.log:

```
161.69.99.11 [01/Aug/2019:03:59:35 +0000] GET /static/js/2.59e222c7.chunk.js HTTP/1.1 200 "https://www.tjbrackett.com/"
```

Literally my first Linux script so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT 2: 
This is the contents of temp1.log before and after the awk.
Before:

```
76.20.106.208 [01/Aug/2019:17:08:40 +0000] GET /static/media/rock.1bacda84.jpg HTTP/1.1 200 "https://www.tjbrackett.com/about"
```

After:

```
76.20.106.208 [01/Aug/2019:17:08:40 +0000] GET /static/media/rock.1bacda84.jpg HTTP/1.1 200 "https://www.tjbrackett.com/about"
```

EDIT 3:
It seems the output is correct but for whatever reason, the response from the Express app is being weird. Also, the only issue now is that there is an extra set of quotations around the URL.

Comment: I tried your code and got no backslashes in the output. What OS do you use and what version of awk? Can you please also provide few lines from  the file  temp1.log.

Comment: I'd suggest using Perl, python, or another language with json libraries instead.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and awk is 4.2.1. I'll add the entire script in an edit. If I remove the lines it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Post your input code.

Comment: post your `temp1.log` contents (a testable fragement)